# Calculating $ \int_{\partial B_2(0)} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(z-3)(z^{13}-1)} $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$\newcommand{\ind}{\mathrm{ind}}
\newcommand{\out}{\mathrm{out}}
\newcommand{\ins}{\mathrm{ins}}
\newcommand{\res}{\mathrm{res}}
\newcommand{\ord}{\mathrm{ord}}$

I want to calculate

$\int_{\partial B_2(0)} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(z-3)(z^{13}-1)}  $

using residue theorem. I want to keep it very simple.  The exercise is taken from Freitag, Complex Analysis. The solution is given by $-2\pi i (3^{13}-1)$. He solved it with a theorem we never had in lecture.

**My Idea:** $I:=\int_{\partial B_2(0)} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(z-3)(z^{13}-1)}$
\begin{align*}
 I&= 2 \pi i \sum_{j=1}^{k} \res(f(z),z_j) \underbrace{\ind(2 \mathrm{e}^{2\pi i t}, z_j )}_{=1} \\
 &= 2 \pi i \bigg[ \res( f,3) + \res(f,1) + \res(f,-(-1)^{1/13}) + \res(f, (-1)^{2/13}) \\
 &+ \dots + \res(f, (-1)^{12/13})  \bigg]  \\
 &= 2 \pi i \bigg[ \frac{1}{3^{13} -1} - \frac{1}{26} +  \res(f,-(-1)^{1/13}) + \res(f, (-1)^{2/13}) + \dots + \res(f, (-1)^{12/13}) \bigg]
\end{align*}
I used $\res(f/g,a) = f(a)/g'(a)$ with $f(z)=1$, $g(z)=(z-3)(z^{13}-1)$ and  $g'(z) = -3(z^{13}-1) + (z-3)13z^{2}$. 
Now I have to calculate all these residues, but is there some faster way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the substitution $x\mapsto\frac{1}{z}$

$$I=\oint_{\partial B_2(0)}\frac{dx}{(x-3)(x^{13}-1)} = \oint_{\partial B_{1/2}(0)}\frac{z^{12} dz}{(1-3z)(1-z^{13})}$$
and we just have to compute the residue at $z=\frac{1}{3}$ of the last integrand function, since that is the only pole of $\frac{z^{12}}{(1-3z)(1-z^{13})}$ enclosed by $\partial B_{1/2}(0)$. It is a simple pole, hence
$$ I = 2\pi i \lim_{z\to\frac{1}{3}}\frac{\left(z-\frac{1}{3}\right) z^{12}}{(1-3z)(1-z^{13})}=\frac{-2\pi i}{3^{13}-1}. $$

Comment: Why are the other residues for $(1-z^{13})$ not important ?

Comment: @Leviathan: because the poles of $\frac{1}{1-z^{13}}$ fall *outside* the new integration path.

Comment: I think the sign may be wrong. There is one negative from the derivative of  $\frac1z$ and one from the change of orientation.

Comment: @robjohn: you are right, now fixing.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\left|\frac1{(z-3)\left(z^{13}-1\right)}\right|\sim\frac1{|z|^{14}}$, the integral over any circle with radius larger than $3$ would be $0$.

Next, we have the residue at the simple singularity $z=3$ to be
$$
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=3}\left(\frac1{(z-3)\left(z^{13}-1\right)}\right)=\frac1{3^{13}-1}
$$
The sum of the residues of the other singularities must therefore be $-\frac1{3^{13}-1}$. Thus,
$$
\int_{B_2(0)}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(z-3)\left(z^{13}-1\right)}=-\frac{2\pi i}{3^{13}-1}
$$